# How to solve this hibernate runtime exception?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, hibernate-mapping, runtimeexception

I am trying to run following code in eclipse

```
package com.trial;


import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;

public class AddStudent {

     private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    System.out.println("ENTER YOUR NAME");
    String name = d.readLine();
    System.out.println("ENTER YOUR DEGREE");
    String degree = d.readLine();
    System.out.println("ENTER YOUR PHONE");
    int phone = Integer.parseInt(d.readLine());
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Degree: " + degree);
    System.out.println("Phone: " + phone);
    if ((name.equals("") || degree.equals(""))) {
        System.out.println("Information Required");
    }
    else {

        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("com//xml//hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Student stu = new Student();
        stu.setName(name);
        stu.setDegree(degree);
        stu.setPhone(phone);
        s.save(stu);
        System.out.println("Added to Database");
        if (s != null)
            s.close();
    }
}
}
```

But getting Runtime exception during creating session factory object that **Unable to read XML.**

I am using following xml files

1. hibernate.cfg.xml

   ```
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
     "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
          <hibernate-configuration>

      <session-factory name="studentFactory">

   <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
   <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ganeshdb</property>
   <property name="connection.username">****</property>
   <property name="connection.password">****</property>
   <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
   <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
   <mapping resource="com//xml//student.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>

   </hibernate-configuration>
   ```
2. Mapping File

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0"? encoding='UTF-8'?>
     <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

     <hibernate-mapping>

       <class name="com.trial.Student" table="studentdemo">
     <id name="id" type="int" column="ID">
                   <generator class="increment" />
     </id>
      <property name="name" column="name" />
      <property name="degree" column="degree" />
      <property name="phone" column="phone" />
   </class>

       </hibernate-mapping>
   ```

plz help.

Comment: post more of the exception message. But at a guess, the xml file is not where you tell the program it should be.

Comment: Runtime Exception:
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML

Answer (score 0):

```
<mapping resource="student.hbm.xml" />
```

and make sure it is in same direcotry as hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Both xml files are in same directory

Comment: I have taken all xml files & class files in default pkg now .But still geting  exception                                                                                                                        Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at AddStudent.main(AddStudent.java:37)